# @WebMvcTest doesn't work properly (401 and 404 errors)

Tags: spring, testing, controller, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

**Note**: this is **solved**, but it's worth being here, as I think it can help a lot of people. Also, some of the code is in spanish because that's my first language.

So, let me start by bitching. I think testing in Spring is a bit of a clusterfuck. A lot of people do the same thing differently, I'm talking different versions of JUnit, different annotations that can be used to solve the same problem, complex annotations and ways that solve the problem but are not conceptually correct. I would LOVE a video that dives deep into it, without just stopping at the basics. But that's that, let's get to the problem.

The problem I had happened when I was creating a `@WebMvcTest(ClienteController.class)` to test my `ClienteController`. I specifically wanted to do a `@WebMvcTest` instead of a `@SpringBootTest`, because this wasn't an Integration test, even though that could have solved the issues. The problems were that, first, it wasn't getting the custom security configuration correctly, and second, that it couldn't find the endpoint, even though when running the application normally, it was all ok.

So the first thing that happened was that I needed to provide a bean of type `CircuitBreakerRegistry` for my controller (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77119821/cant-use-a-controlleradvice-with-exceptionhandlers-while-using-circuit-breaker) for reference), that in my case, I had in my custom `CircuitBreakerConfiguration`. I saw that you could archive what I wanted with two annotations: `@ContextConfiguration` and `@Import`. I decided to use the first one because I just thought it was more declarative (BIG MISTAKE), so the code ended up like this:

```java
@WebMvcTest(ClienteController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(CircuitBreakerConfiguration.class)
public class ClienteControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    ClienteService clienteService;

    @Test
    public void siNoSeAutenticaDevuelveUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/clientes")
                .param("tipoDocumento", "0")
                .param("nroDocumento", "10000000"))
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    public void siSeAutenticaMalDevuelveUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/clientes")
                .param("tipoDocumento", "0")
                .param("nroDocumento", "10000000")
                .with(httpBasic("user", "password"))
            )
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    public void siSeAutenticaBienPasaLaRequest() throws Exception {
        //dado
        when(clienteService.getCliente(anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(null);

        //entonces
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/clientes")
                .param("tipoDocumento", "0")
                .param("nroDocumento", "10000000")
                .with(httpBasic("admin", "password"))
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

**Now I didn't get the error, and the first tests passed, but the final one didn't.** That was because the last test is supposed to be a correct request and **excpect a 200, but instead I got 401 (like in every other test)**. After researching, specially here since there are a lot of questions about that, I came to understand that it wasn't using my custom security configuration, but rahter the default, so I also had to include the `SecurityConfig` here. After trying a bit, I also added `@ActiveProfiles("test")` and a `application-test.yml` file under `src/test/resources`, because in `SecurityConfig`, I created an in memory user with a username and password defined as secrets in my `application.yml`. So after all of that, the annotations were as follows:

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ClienteController.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CircuitBreakerConfiguration.class, SecurityConfig.class})
```

**This ended up solving the issue, but the tests didn't pass yet, as now I got 404 instead of 401** (meaning the security was set up correctly, but for some reason it didn't find the endpoint). After researching again, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548771/spring-boot-test-for-controller-fails-with-404-code) post, in which the first answer says that adding `@Import(ClienteController.class)` would solve the issue, and that for some reason `@WebMvcTest(ClienteController.class)` wasn't including the `ClienteController` in the context correctly. I also learned that excluding the autoconfiguration didn't do anything, so it ended up being like this:

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ClienteController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CircuitBreakerConfiguration.class, SecurityConfig.class})
@Import(ClienteController.class)
```

**And this finally worked, and all tests passed.** So the conclusion that people reached in that post, in that answer, was that `@ContextConfiguration` **doesn't add, but overwrites which classes are put into the context**, thus the `ClienteController.class` part of `@WebMvcTest(controllers = ClienteController.class)` was overwitten. So the final version, adding some other needed configurations, is this:

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ClienteController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Import({CircuitBreakerConfiguration.class,
    RetryConfiguration.class,
    RateLimiterConfiguration.class,
    SecurityConfig.class})
```

So........ ok? If there's something I want to ask is what's up with `@ContextConfiguration` and `@Import`?, as they seem to try to solve the same issue, with the difference that one overrides and one doesn't. Also, is that the only difference? When would you actilvely go for `@ContextConfiguration` instead of `@Import`?

Comment: What made you decide to include an `@ContextConfiguration` in the first place? All web related configurations will be automatically included, including security etc. But the `@ContextConfiguration` is, as the name implied, for the configuration this is to be used if you want to specify the full configuration. That `@Import` works with tests is an, imho, an unfortunate side-effect of that annotation. The `@Import` can be used with regular components as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum as I said, i needed to include my `CircuitBreakerConfiguration`, because it wasn't included by default and it was needed for the controller to initalize (constructor injection). I also used it to include my personal `SecurityConfig`, because, without it, it was using a default security configuration (secured all endpoints, no valid user, etc.).
What you say here is also worring, that about `@Import` working with tests being a side effect. I mean, how would you load any extra config without it? Populating `@ContextConfiguration` ? Or maybe just using `application-test.yml`?

Comment: If you want to configure it yourself you should use `@ContextConfiguration` and add everything that is needed. If your `SecurityConfig` wasn't included it wasn't included due to not being `@EnableWebSecurity` (maybe that was on a different class?). You can always use the `includeFilters` on the `@WebMvcTest` to add a pattern to include additionally. The `@Import` side-effect is IMNHO and others will probably differ in that. Finally you can also add an `@TestConfiguration` static class to your test for the additional/custom configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum I had `@EnableWebSecurity` in my `@Configuration` file, and I had to import the `SecurityConfig.class` like you saw before, otherwise it wouldn't pick it up. I also tried moving the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation to the main application (under `@SpringBootApplication`), but no luck. I'm using Spring Boot 3.1.2, by the way.